# Modify links in user comments

Tags: comments, links

When a link is posted in a comment, the format is : rel="nofollow"

Using a function, how can I change that to : rel="external nofollow _blank"

So the links open in a new window?

Comment: please post your wp_list_comments() section and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

> To replace `nofollow` with `nofollow external _blank`

Put this code in your theme's `functions.php` file to replace text as required.

```
function wpse_60668_relnofollow($text) {
    $return = str_replace('nofollow', 'external nofollow _blank', $text);
    return $return;
}

add_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'wpse_60668_relnofollow'); //this'll change author link
add_filter('comment_text', 'wpse_60668_relnofollow'); //This'll change the content
```